# For how long has "plead" been used as a verb counterpart to "plea" (noun) even though both words historically have both verb and noun forms?

Tags: etymology, historical-change

In modern writing about legal affairs, it is common to say something along the lines of:

> The judge heard his guilty **plea**.

and

> He decided to **plead** guilty.

It seems to me like in this legal sense of the words, "plead" is used as a verb while "plea" is used as a noun, even in a context where both represent the same concept.

As a simple example, consider this opening sentence from [Wikipedia's page on "plea bargain,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plea_bargain) which uses "plead" as a verb, almost as if it were an inflection of the same word.

> The **plea bargain** (also **plea** agreement, **plea** deal, copping a **plea**, or **plea** in mitigation) is any agreement in a criminal case between the prosecutor and defendant whereby the defendant agrees to **plead** guilty to a particular charge in return for some concession from the prosecutor.

Yet according to the *OED*, the two words have totally separate etymologies, and both words have a noun form and verb form.

> **Plea**: < Anglo-Norman and Old French *plaid* (842 in Old French in the Strasbourg Oaths in sense ‘pact, agreement’; French *plaid* ; compare α forms), Anglo-Norman *pleet, pleit, plete*,
>
> **Plead**: < Anglo-Norman *plaider, plaidier, pleder, pledire, pledre, pleider, pleidier* and Old French *pledeer, pledier*, Old French, Middle French *plaidier*

Have these words, despite their separate etymologies, always been used in a somewhat interchangeable way, as in the Wikipedia quote? Or is that a more recent phenomenon resulting from the similarity of the words?

---

**Edit**: It seems people are either finding this question unclear or disliking it.  Let me add a clarification that I also posted as a comment.

I understand that the words are not exactly used "interchangeably." My point is that both "plea" and "plead" are both nouns and verbs, and neither word derived from the other in English.  So hypothetically, one could say:

> I **plea** guilty.

Or

> He gave a guilty **plead.**

But today, it appears we always use "plead" as a verb and "plea" as a noun, often both referring to the notion of:

> a *legal **plea** where one **pleads** guilty or not guilty*.

My question is why that is and for how long.

Comment: Where are they used interchangeably? One is a noun, and the other is a verb. And how are their etymologies "separate"?

Comment: @Mick I struggled to find a better word than "interchangeably."  My point is that both "plea" and "plead" are both nouns and verbs, and neither word derived from the other in English.  So hypothetically, one could say "I plea guilty."  Or "He gave a guilty plead."  But today, it appears we always use "plead" as a verb and "plea" as a noun, often both referring to the notion of a *legal **plea** where one **pleads** guilty or not guilty*.  My question is why that is and for how long.

Comment: Etymology Online seems to show that both forms derive from the Medieval Latin *placitum* (lawsuit). I don't see the problem, but then I'm not an etymologist. The roots seem to be well-established with the Old French.

Comment: @Mick when I said "separate etymologies" I meant that one word was not derived from the other *within English*.  Our tendency to use "plea" as a noun and "plead" as a verb in the same context might not have always been the case, and hence the question.

Comment: They are not “both nouns and verbs”. The verb use of *plea* documented by the OED almost always is written *plea’d*: you have to go back more than 200 years to find otherwise. This is strictly informal at best. The noun use of *plead* is obsolete. Lastly, to say that “neither was derived from the other in English” obscures the fact that these entered English via French where of course they were extremely closely related. You would not say that the noun *cloth* and the verb *clothe* “were unrelated”, and it is the same here.

Comment: @tchrist I understand your points, but I stand by every word of mine that you quoted, albeit not the one misquoted (I never said anything was or "were unrelated"):  //  "both nouns and verbs" is certainly true from an etymological perspective, which is the perspective of the question -- I'm asking when we arrived at the modern convention.  "neither was derived from the other in English" is still true, regardless of the facts it obscures. :)

Comment: It would have been helpful if, at the outset, you have given examples of noun and verb usages for both words.

Comment: I would have cited examples from literature, or newspapers,  where the two words seem to be used in similar circumstances. I'm not convinced that your first example is actually heard or written. It sounds like the accused is supplicating. The following sounds much better: "The judge heard the [accused plead guilty](https://www.google.com/search?ei=3iBfWqfEIoiLU5GPmOAC&q=%22accused+plead+guilty%22&oq=%22accused+plead+guilty%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i7i30k1l2j0i7i5i30k1l3j0i8i30k1l2.5647.5647.0.6946.1.1.0.0.0.0.157.157.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.156....0.1YY5GqtVk1o)"

Answer (score 5):

According to the following [source](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/the-noun-is-%E2%80%9Cplea%E2%80%9D-the-verb-is-%E2%80%9Cplead%E2%80%9D/) the use of *plea as a verb* is a regionalism, while *plead as a noun* is just a non-standard usage:

> In general use, ***the verb plead*** means
>
> - *to make an earnest appeal, entreaty, or supplication; to beg, implore*.
>
> The ***noun plea*** has similar legal and general meanings:
>
> ***plea***:
>   - 1. *A suit or action at law; the presentation of an action in court.
>   An urgent, emotional request, an entreaty; (also) an unarticulated appeal*.
>
> ***Used as a verb in place of plead, plea can be regarded as a regionalism (Chiefly Eng. regional [north.], and [Sc](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/plea). Now also U.S.)***:
>
> - *If you plea guilty and then later in another hearing say th(at you didn’t do it, can you be charged with perjury? –example of U.S. usage in OED*
>
> ***Using the verb form plead for the noun plea, however, is jarringly nonstandard:***
>
> - *A Plead to Sinners –title of a poem on a religious site*
> - *A plead to ban homophobia –headline on a college site*
> - *A plead for help –part of a blog title*
>
> ***In each of these examples, the word wanted is plea.***

Also from [blog.bennettandbennett.com](http://blog.bennettandbennett.com/2007/12/plea-plead-pleaded-pled-please/):

> When a person admits her guilt in court, she does not plea guilty. She pleads guilty, entering a guilty plea. ***“Plead” is a verb. “Plea” is a noun***.
>
> After a person has admitted his guilt in court, he has not plead (or “pleaed”) guilty. The past tense of [“to plead” is “pleaded” or “pled.](https://jakubmarian.com/pleaded-guilty-vs-pled-guilty-which-one-is-correct/)”

So, referring to regional, non-standard usages, most likely due to the similarity of the spelling of the two terms, it is really hard to find a precise period when it all started. [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20plead%20for%2C%20plea%20guilty&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20plead%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplea%20guilty%3B%2Cc0), if it can be of any real help here, suggest usages of *a plead for* and *plea guilty* from the mid-20th century.

Comment: I think you'll also find *plea* used as a verb when it is short for *plea **bargain***, as in "they *plea'd* it down to time served". In that sense I don't think it's regional (unless the "region" is the whole US legal system).

Comment: The distinction I was trying to make is between "plea" substituted for the verb "plead", which I don't think is common or widespread in the US, and "plea" substituted for the verb "plea bargain", which is. The "US" quote does not sound like a proper legal usage (but perhaps a question that a non-legally-trained defendant would ask), so I can buy "plea" for "plead" as "regional" within the US. But "plea" used to mean something like "negotiate about the sentence that the prosecutor puts on the table" *is* a common legal usage. The OED does not make this distinction, perhaps because this kind...

Comment: ...of plea bargaining is not a regular feature of the British legal system.